# Post-creation callback: How to run code immediately after ctor?

Tags: swift, swift2

I wonder if I can get a callback after `init()`, or perhaps before `deinit()`.

I have this repeating pattern in my code. First `init()` is run. Next `fire()` function is run.

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func redButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        PickedColorEvent(color: UIColor.redColor(), name: "RED").fire()
    }
    @IBAction func greenButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        PickedColorEvent(color: UIColor.greenColor(), name: "GREEN").fire()
    }
    @IBAction func blueButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        PickedColorEvent(color: UIColor.blueColor(), name: "BLUE").fire()
    }
    @IBAction func resetButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        ResetEvent().fire()
    }
}
```

Desired code, without calling the `fire()` function. I want it to **autofire** after creation. My code always run on the main-thread, so I guess I could use a one-shot timer for this. However I'm looking for a solution without timers.

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func redButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        PickedColorEvent(color: UIColor.redColor(), name: "RED")
    }
    @IBAction func greenButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        PickedColorEvent(color: UIColor.greenColor(), name: "GREEN")
    }
    @IBAction func blueButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        PickedColorEvent(color: UIColor.blueColor(), name: "BLUE")
    }
    @IBAction func resetButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        ResetEvent()
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get rid of the `fire()` function?

### Update 1 (thanks feedback from @luk2302)

The event classes inherit from a protocol. I could change the protocol to a class or a struct, and call `fire()` within the base class. However then I decide wether the subclasses can be struct or class.

When just invoking `ResetEvent()` without using the result, then I get the `Result of initializer is unused`. I wish there was a reserved keyword for suppressing that warning.

Comment: you can simply call `fire` as the last statement in the init function of ResetEvent!

Comment: Argh, indeed, silly me. I have updated the post with more info about my setup.

Comment: "...decide wether the subclasses can be struct or class". subclass  can not be a struct :-). If we talking about protocol, we talking about conformance with protocol, not about inheritance

Comment: Conformance, yes. Thank you @user3441734

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use fire function after you initialised all stored properties as you can call any other function defined in your class and / or struct

```
protocol P {}
extension P {
    func fire(s: String) {
        print("fire from \(s)")
    }
}
class C:P {
    var i: Int
    init(i:Int) {
        self.i = i
        foo()
        fire("class init i: \(self.i)")
    }
    deinit {
        fire("class deinit i: \(i)")
    }
    func foo() {
        i += 1
    }
}

struct S:P {
    var i: Int
    init(i: Int){
        self.i = i
        foo()
        fire("struct init i: \(self.i)")
    }
    mutating func foo() {
        i += 10
    }

}

C(i: 5)
S(i: 1)

/*
fire from class init i: 6
fire from struct init i: 11
fire from class deinit i: 6
*/
```

If you want to avoid compiler warning "Result of initializer is unused", just use next syntax

```
_ = C(i: 5)
_ = S(i: 1)
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I have asked this silly question. Your code is very close to what I want. However there is a "Result of initializer is unused" warning and I don't want the classes/structs implementing the protocol, to invoke `fire()` themselves. I guess I want some language feature that doesn't exist.

Comment: @neoneye to avoid the compiler warning see my update

Comment: This solves what I asked. Sadly I'm no way nearer my desired code.